exam class automatically total fillin
I'm trying to make it so that I can automatically ascertain the number of fillin gaps, and hence the total points, without having to count them.
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\newcounter{fillintotal}

\question[\the\value{fillintotal}]  
Text with \fillin[blank]\addtocounter{fillintotal}{1}.
Text with \fillin[blank]\addtocounter{fillintotal}{1}.
Text with \fillin[blank]\addtocounter{fillintotal}{1}.
Text with \fillin[blank]\addtocounter{fillintotal}{1}.
Text with \fillin[blank]\addtocounter{fillintotal}{1}.

Counter fillintotal is at \arabic{fillintotal}

\end{questions}

\end{document}


Can you be a little bit more explicit about what you want to achieve? Is it just that you want to avoid having to add \addcounter{fillintotal}{1} explicitly? This can be easily done by defining a custom macro that creates the blank space and increments the counter.

No, sorry, I know that but was trying to keep the example as minimal and simple as possible. I'd like the question points to be totalled based on the amounts of fillin.

Note that \question is expanded before the counter is ready.  To revese time, LaTeX uses the aux file, in this case \label and \ref.  IIRC, exam does more than just print the number of points, so one needs \getrefnumber instead of just \ref.  Also, it takes two runs to work.
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{refcount}% or hyperref

\newcounter{fillintotal}[question]% automatically reset to 0
\let\oldfillin=\fillin
\def\fillin{\refstepcounter{fillintotal}\oldfillin}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question[\getrefnumber{fillin\thequestion}]  
Text with \fillin[blank].
Text with \fillin[blank].
Text with \fillin[blank].
Text with \fillin[blank].
Text with \fillin[blank].
\label{fillin\thequestion}

Counter fillintotal is at \arabic{fillintotal}

\end{questions}

\end{document}


Amazing thank you
